# Como carregar relacionamentos em vários níveis?

Tags: php, laravel, relacionamento

Olá, estou tentando realizar buscas em 3 tabelas relacionadas da seguinte forma contracts belongsTo -> companies  hasMany -> company_addresses.  Gostaria de exibir dados de company_addresses  na view de contracts.

```
contracts
    id – integer
    company_id - integer
    title – string 

companies
    id - integer
    name – string

company_addresses
    id - integer
    company_id - integer
    address – string
    complement – string
    contact– string
```

Model contracts

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'company_id', 'id');
}
```

Model companies

```
public function contracts ()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Contract::class);
} 
public function addresses()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CompanyAddress::class);
}
```

Model company_addresses

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}
```

Código do Controller de Contract

```
 public function index()
 {
     $contract= Contract::with('companies.company_addresses')->get();
     return view(‘contract.view')->with(compact('contract'));
 }
```

Então, o que estou fazendo errado e como posso corrigir? Qualquer ajuda é muito válida.

Desde de já muito obrigada.